# $φ(t) = \int f(t, ω)dμ(ω)$ defines a real-valued continuous function on $(a,b)$

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(Ω, A, μ)$ be a measure space and $a < b$ be any two real numbers. Suppose $f$ is a real-valued function on $(a, b) × Ω$ such that (i) $\forall t ∈ (a, b)$, the function $ω \mapsto f(t,ω)$ is A-measurable and (ii) $\forall ω ∈ Ω$, the function $t \mapsto f(t,ω)$ is continuous on $(a,b)$.
>
> Show that if $ \exists μ-integrable$ function $g$ on $Ω$ such that $|f(t,ω)| \le g(ω) , \forall(t,ω)$, then $φ(t) = \int f(t, ω)dμ(ω)$ defines a real-valued continuous function on $(a,b)$.

My attempt:

$\forall ω ∈ Ω$,the function $t \mapsto f(t,ω)$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ and hence measurable on $\beta(a,b)$. Also, $\forall t ∈ (a, b)$, the function $ω \mapsto f(t,ω)$ is A-measurable.

**I don't know how to conclude from the above two lines that $f : (a,b) \times \Omega \to \Bbb R$ is measurable w.r.t the product measure.**

If, $f : (a,b) \times \Omega \to \Bbb R$ is indeed measurable w.r.t the product measure and $ \exists μ-integrable$ function $g$ on $Ω$ such that $|f(t,ω)| \le g(ω) , \forall(t,ω)$ , then it seems that Dominated Convergence Theorem should suffice.

It will be extremely helpful if details can be provided. Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to prove joint measurability. Let $t_n \to t$. To show that $\int f(t_n,\omega) d\mu(\omega) \to \int f(t,\omega) d\mu (\omega)$ you can apply DCT.

Comment: Yeah, but in order to do so don't we need the measurability of $f$ in the product measure?

Comment: No. I am fixing $t_n$ converging to $t$ and considering the sequence if measurable functions $g_n$ defined by $g_n(\omega)=f(t_n,\omega)$. Each of these function is measurable by hypothesis.

Comment: Right! Thank you!

Comment: @ThatIs Just for information, it is also true that $f$ is jointly measurable. You can prove this by writing it as the pointwise limit of the functions $F_n(t,\omega)=f(\frac {[nt]} n,\omega)$ and  verifying that each $F_n$ is jointly measurable.

Comment: I've posted another question measure theory today : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2961646/mathscrt-contains-all-%cf%83s-measurable-real-valued-functions-on-%ce%a9  , if you could give some important insights on that, it'll be really helpful.